# PDO fetch issue from two table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables in my database and I want to get all usernames from table 1 where all usernames in my order table 2 and I have a 2 or 3 difficult ways to do it and it's very hard through fetch Data in a while loop if somebody can help to make it easy

So I think its so clear now in the sketch
I want to see all username data from Table 2 if their username storge in table 2

thank you for helping.

[image]

```
<?php


$showUserOrder = array('ordered'=>'User 1','ordered'=>'User 2','ordered'=>'User 2');

$userwithorder = 'SELECT * FROM usersdata WHERE username = :ordered';
$sttmsosd = $pdo->prepare($userwithorder);
$sttmsosd->execute($showUserOrder);
$GetUserWithOrder =  $sttmsosd->fetchAll();



foreach($GetUserWithOrder as $gethasorder){
?>
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-1 info"># <?php echo $gethasorder['id'] ;?></td>
    <td class="col-md-1 info"><img src="../<?php echo $gethasorder['username'] ;?>" width="40" alt=""></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: nice sketch; where's the code for it all?

Comment: this is how things work with tags; people expect relevant code for them; you have none, so that makes the question both unclear and too broad. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thank you ill added the code right now

Comment: How is pdo related

Comment: Hint: MySQL's INNER JOIN.  ...   `SELECT [....] FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.orderUser = table2.username`

Comment: I update the Question post

Comment: @RaymondNijland it worked very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
SELECT
   table1.OrderID,
   table2.username
   ...
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    table2 
    ON table1.orderUser = table2.username
```